# Pull data that has just been stored into a database using only one button

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating my very own marketing funnel for my website. How do I get the id of the record I've just saved onto my ajax call without having to use any additional buttons or user triggered methods.

I have created a modal which shows after a user registers their details onto our system as way of the system to interact with the user. Anyway, from this stage onwards, there should be multiple questions being asked to the user about their preferences and the products they want. In my head this just means that I should be updating that user's information the minute that first modal pops up.

Ajax call for saving user info:

```
$("#btn-save-client").click(function () {
    var clientData = {
        id: $('#id').val(),
        firstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
        lastName: $('#LastName').val(),
        cellNo: $('#CellNo').val(),
        emailAddress: $('#EmailAddress').val(),
        country: $('#Country').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Home/SaveClientData',
        data: JSON.stringify(clientData), //Serialises the form's elements.
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#contactForm").append('<div class="overlay"><span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></span></div>');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#contactForm .overlay").remove();
            $("#contactForm")[0];
            LoadFirstFunnel(data.id);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(error.responseText);
            alert(error.responseText);
        },
        completed: function () {
            $("#contactForm .overlay").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

C# method for saving in `HomeController.cs`:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveClientData([FromBody]ClientData clientDataModel)
{
   if (clientDataModel == null) return new JsonResult(new {id = null, error = "Please fill in all the details required."});

   var _addClientData = new HomeTransactions(new PetaConnection().db()).SaveClient(clientDataModel);
   return new JsonResult(new { id = _addClientData.id, error = null });
}
```

From my HomeController.cs, my code goes to the following code to save data into the database and then return values:

```
public string SaveClient(ClientData clientDataModel)
{
   try
   {
      ClientInfo clientModel = new ClientInfo();
      ClientCompanyInfo clientCompanyModel = new ClientCompanyInfo();
      if (clientModel.id == 0 && clientCompanyModel.id == 0)
      {
         clientCompanyModel.CompanyName = "Default Inc.";
         _connect.Save(clientCompanyModel);
         Random rand = new Random();
         int randomNo = rand.Next(10000, 20000);
         string referenceNo = "MTP-" + randomNo;
         clientModel.ReferenceNo = referenceNo;
         clientModel.FirstName = clientDataModel.FirstName;
         clientModel.LastName = clientDataModel.LastName;
         clientModel.CellNo = clientDataModel.CellNo;
         clientModel.EmailAddress = clientDataModel.EmailAddress;
         clientModel.Country = clientDataModel.Country;
         clientModel.companyId = clientCompanyModel.id;
         clientModel.Active = 1;
         clientModel.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
         clientModel.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
         _connect.Save(clientModel);
         clientDataModel.id = clientModel.id;
       }
       return clientModel.id.ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        throw;
     }
}
```

Ajax call for `LoadFirstFunnel` mentioned in the previous Ajax call.

```
function LoadFirstFunnel(clientId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Home/_OpenFirstPanelModal',
        data: { clientId: clientId }, // serializes the form's elements.
        beforeSend: function (data) {
            $("#MessageBoxModal").append('<div class="overlay"><span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></span></div>');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            id = data.id;
            $("#MessageBoxModal  .overlay").remove();
            $('#MessageBoxModal .modal-title').html('Your information was successfully added.');
            $('#MessageBoxModal .btn-style-one').attr('id', 'btn-notification');
            $('#MessageBoxModal .btn-style-one').attr('id', 'btn-deny-note');
            $('#MessageBoxModal .btn-style-one').attr('data-id', '');
            $('#MessageBoxModal #regNote').html(data);
            $('#MessageBoxModal .modal-dialog').css('width', '');
            $('#MessageBoxModal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false,
                show: true
            });

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            $("#MessageBoxModal  .overlay").remove();
            alert(error);
        },
        completed: function (data) {
            $("#MessageBoxModal .overlay").remove();
        }
    });
};
```

C# call on HomeController.cs which responds to the LoadFirstFunnel ajax call:

```
public ActionResult _OpenFirstPanelModal(int clientId)
{
   ClientInfo _openClientInfoModel = new ClientInfo();
   _openClientInfoModel = new HomeTransactions(new PetaConnection().db()).OpenClientInfo(clientId);
   return PartialView("_OpenFirstPanelModal", _openClientInfoModel);
}
```

`Modal.cshtml` that pops up after registration:

```
@model MotseThePowerHouse_Website.Models.ClientInfo
<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.id" name="id" />
    <div class="text-muted text-center col-sm-12" id="msgDisplay">
        <h4>Some text here...</h4>
        <h4>Some text here...</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <a id="btn-notification" data-id="@Model.id" class="theme-btn btn-style-one">Yes, notify me</a>
    <a id="btn-deny-note" data-id="@Model.id" class="theme-btn btn-style-one">No, thank you</a>
</div>
```

I know this is all jumbled and it is not working although the logic could make sense, I want to know of other methods out there which can be used by me to deliver this funnel output.

Below is my ClientInfo Model:

```
using System;

namespace MotseThePowerHouse_Website.Models
{
    public class ClientInfo
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string ReferenceNo { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string UnitNo { get; set; }
        public string UnitStreetName { get; set; }
        public string ComplexNo { get; set; }
        public string ComplexName { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }
        public string Suburb { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string CellNo { get; set; }
        public string TelephoneNo { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public string BlogNotification { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public string PositionHeld { get; set; }
        public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
        public int Active { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Are the controller methods actually being hit?

Comment: Mark your controller methods with [HttpPost] attributes

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin Yeah, I've been getting a zero or empty value on my output. So that's the problem is.

Comment: Did you decorate your controller methods with [HttpPost]?

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin Yes, I did. And I'm still getting the same problem where even if I impose a value into a variable, it still comes back as zero. A method called SaveClientData has a back-end method in it called SaveClient, it was in this back-end method where I forced a value in and the minute it's done reading this method and has to go back to the controller to finish up the rest of the code with all the values present, my id has a zero although before the controller, SaveClient brought an id with a proper value. But I'm still looking into successfully apply your solutions though...

Comment: Just a quick test: add `[FromBody]` before `string firstName` in your SaveClientData and tell me if it comes populated.

Comment: @CiubotariuFlorin It's edited, please check again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class which will represent your request body:

```
public class ClientData
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string CellNo {get;set;}
    public string EmailAddress {get;set;}
    public string Country {get;set;}
}
```

Modify your `SaveClientData` method to the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveClientData([FromBody]ClientData clientData)
{
    if (clientDataModel == null) return Json(new {error = "Please fill in all the details required."}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

     var _addClientData = new HomeTransactions(new PetaConnection().db()).SaveClient(clientDataModel);
     return Json(new {id = _addClientData}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and your JavaScript code:

```
var clientData = {
  firstName : $('#FirstName').val(),
  lastName: $('#LastName').val(),
  cellNo: $('#CellNo').val(),
  emailAddress: $('#EmailAddress').val(),
  country: $('#Country').val()
}


 $.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(clientData),
    contentType:"application/json",
    success: function(data){
        if(data.error) { return;}
        $("#contactForm .overlay").remove();
        $("#contactForm")[0];
        LoadFirstFunnel(data.id);
    }
 });
```

and for the second part you have to modify the parameter name from `id` to `clientId`:

```
public ActionResult _OpenFirstPanelModal(int clientId)
```

Comment: Okay, clientData variable in the ajax call does get client data from the form. Only when it hits the controller then it gives null values. I even that maybe "data: JSON.stringify(clientData)," was responsible for this and took back to "data: { clientData: clientData }," and still find that it still gives null values...

Comment: Can you edit the question and put your new code there?

Comment: @MotseMo I've edited my answer. Add `contentType:"application/json"` also.

Comment: Hi there, it seems to be working properly in C#. But now I've quiet trying to figure out how to bring back the value onto my ajax call so that it can go through LoadFirstFunnel(data.id). I used data.id with the hope that it will have changed my initial id value in the top variable to the one we pulled from the database...

Comment: Can you update your code with the latest version? Based on the code you supplied we do not know what your API returns to the client.

Comment: What is the content of `_addClientData` variable? What is returns?

Comment: It returns all data by specified id from ClientInfo table.

Comment: Can you show us how `ClientInfo` looks like? If you provide that then I can help you.

Comment: I've edited my answer. In case it solves your problem, can you mark the answer as "correct"?

Comment: I may probably be missing a namespace on my controller, alhough Json can be seen as an existing things but there's two error messages, one which says "No overload for method 'Json' takes 0 arguments" and JsonResult brings "Non-invocable member 'JsonResult' cannot be used like a method.". Could I be missing something?

Comment: Oups. Missed a `new` keyword. It should be `return new JsonResult`.

Comment: Is it return new JsonResult({... on the first and the last line of SaveClientData([FromBody]...)? If yes, then the variables in each JsonResult are missing definitions...

Comment: I've edited the entire method. I forgot another 3 `new`s.

Comment: I've edited my code also to show you what I got with me. It's still giving errors on JsonResult where it says " 'JsonResult' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" and there's another error on id = null which says "Cannot assign '<null>' to anonymous type property", id = _addClientData.id has an error that says " 'string' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no accessible extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found(...", and the last red line is under error = null saying "Cannot assign '<null>' to anonymous type property".

Comment: I've edited the `SaveClientData` method and success function in JS.

Comment: The only error left right now is on return new JsonResult(...) for both lines which says " 'JsonResult' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Comment: I've modified my answer again. A lot of mistakes on my side. Hope it will be ok for you now.

Comment: Add `System.Web.Mvc` namespace and remove `new` keyword before `Json` as in my edited answer.